# Convert dynamic dataframe with randomly generated fake data to static dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, faker

I'm trying to add a column of fake data into a dataframe.  It doesn't not matter what the contents of the dataframe are.  I just want to add a column of randomly generated fake data, e.g., randomly generated first names with one name per line.  Here is some dummy data to play with but I repeat, the contents of the dataframe do not matter:

```
from faker import Faker

faker = Faker("en_GB")

contact = [faker.profile() for i in range(0, 100)]
contact = spark.createDataFrame(contact)
```

I'm trying to create a class with functions to do this for different columns as so:

```
class anonymise:
        
    @staticmethod
    def FstName():
        def FstName_values():
            faker = Faker("en_GB")
            return faker.first_name()

        FstName_udf = udf(FstName_values, StringType())
        return FstName_udf()
```

The class above has one function as an example but the actual class has multiple functions of exactly the same template, just for different columns, e.g., LastName.

Then, I'm adding in the new columns as so:

```
contact = contact \
.withColumn("FstName", anonymise.FstName())
```

I'm using this process to replace real data with realistic-looking, fake, randomly generated data.

This *appears* to works fine and runs quickly.  However, I noticed that every time I display the new dataframe, it will try to generate an entirely new column:

First try:
[image]

Second try immediately after the first:
[image]

This means that the dataframe isn't just one static dataframe with data and it will try to generate a new column for every subsequent command.  This is causing me issues further down the line when I try to write the data to an external file.

I would just like it to generate the column once with some static data that is easily callable.  I don't even want it to regenerate the same data.  The generation process should happen once.

I've tried copying to a pandas dataframe but the dataframe is too large for this to work (1.3+ million rows) and I can't seem to write a smaller version to an external file anyway.

Any help on this issue appreciated!

Many thanks,

Carolina

Comment: It's because one of your column is tied to a randomly generated value, so every time Spark runs the computation graph it's re-computing the random values.
Would setting a seed value help ?

Comment: Related: [How to fix value produced by Random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805265/how-to-fix-value-produced-by-random)

Comment: Where does this random seed need to be specified? Can I set the whole notebook with it?

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas Yea, try at the top of the notebook.

Comment: @VladSiv Unfortunately I'm still running into the same issue!

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc (to add to above)

Comment: Where you have your random generation, you should have the possibility to pass a seed argument. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028061/pyspark-set-random-seed-for-reproducible-values.
In your case I guess it should be in your Faker function.

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas I've tried with `seed` but it won't work. `df` is evaluated every time and if I set `seed` it will give the same names. It's really annoying. I'll try to think about it, but for now I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: @VladSiv Thanks for looking into it! :)

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas There is a pyspark library (https://pythonrepo.com/repo/wesleywilian-pyspark-anonymizer) to do the anonymize using various different ways, is there a reason you are not using the same?

Comment: @HussainBohra Faker generates random but realistic looking data which is a requirement for what I'm doing.  I'm afraid that library doesn't seem to have that functionality (although I could be reading it wrong!).  Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: I am not suggesting, replacing Faker with pyspark_anonymizer, you can still generate your data with Faker, but then anonymize it using pyspark_anonymizer, I will add a code sample as an answer for you to take a look.

Comment: @HussainBohra I'm using real data though that needs to be anonymised with realistic looking fake data, the data generated using Faker is used to replace columns of real data.  Using pyspark_anonymizer won't replace my real data with realistic fake data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a pretty simple fix in the end...

By putting `faker = Faker("en_GB")` inside the function where it was, I was generating an instance of `faker` for every row.  I simply had to remove it from within the function and generate the instance outside the class.  So now, although it does generate the data every time a command is called, it does so very quickly even for large dataframes and I haven't run into any issues for any subsequent commands.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using spark, it is doing the computation across multiple nodes. What you can try is add a contact.persist() after doing the anonymization.

You can read more about persist [HERE](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-cache-and-persist-explained/).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response!  In theory this would work as it seems to work on the test dataframe with only 100 rows.  However, my actual dataframes have 240+ thousand and 1.3+ million rows in them and .cache() and .persist() don't seem to work well for these (as in I've tried displaying the dataframes after caching/persisting and the command still runs after over half an hour).  Do you have any suggestions for large dataframes?  Thanks :)

Comment: I did some reading on this and as per the documentation mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/jobs/spark-udf-performance#solution, it says that if the dataframes are very big, you should write it into a parquet file first. You can then read it again to get a DF which is persistent. Another option is to convert the original spark df to a pandas df, add the fake column and convert it back to a sparkdf. Both of these options are hacky and may take some time but will work.